# Implementing facebook feed dialog and cross domain environment

Tags: facebook, dialog, cross-domain, feed

I'm trying to implement a Facebook Share widget which will be a link(button) on a client's page. When user clicks on "share" button, dialog will show up, populated with the information(caption, description, etc.) received from our server.

I've tried using Feed Dialog to accomplish this task.

I've gone as far as: - registering my application with Facebook and getting my application ID. - placing feed dialog code onto the test page which is currently located on my local machine.

So, currently my application points to localhost url.

Everything works as expected as Site Url and App domain are set to my local machine url. However, for our purposes we need to trigger this dialog from many different client's pages. So, those URLs will always be different.

I was thinking to use https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php however, as far as I know it doesn't have a callback function which we also need to have.

Do you have any advise on how this can be implemented?